# Jenkins slave not working on mesos

Tags: jenkins, mesos, mesosphere, marathon

I'm using the jenkins mesos plugin for CI.
Initially, I followed the following tutorial: http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2014/05/12/delivering-ebays-ci-solution-with-apache-mesos-part-ii/

but the jenkins itself was not being setup via this. (I got error could not load config.xml file, even there was one)

Then I followed https://rogerignazio.com/blog/scaling-jenkins-mesos-marathon/ 
, and I was able to run jenkins master (jenkin framework/scheduler), but when I define the scripts to run, the jenkins-slaves are not being created. I think I'm missing some configuration regarding slaves. Can you tell me, what's the reason that the slaves are not being created to run jobs.

On the jenkins build page, I'm getting :

```
(pending—Waiting for next available executor)
```

And in the jenkins-logs, i'm getting following error:

```
INFO: Provisioning Jenkins Slave on Mesos with 1 executors. Remaining excess workload: 0 executors)
Jun 19, 2015 4:02:55 PM hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$StandardStrategyImpl apply
INFO: Started provisioning MesosCloud from MesosCloud with 1 executors. Remaining excess workload: 0
Jun 19, 2015 4:02:55 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.MesosComputerLauncher <init>
INFO: Constructing MesosComputerLauncher
Jun 19, 2015 4:02:55 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.MesosSlave <init>
INFO: Constructing Mesos slave mesos-jenkins-1f8691df-9918-4175-87b3-bcc3de80b258 from cloud 
Jun 19, 2015 4:03:05 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.MesosComputerLauncher launch
INFO: Launching slave computer mesos-jenkins-1f8691df-9918-4175-87b3-bcc3de80b258
Jun 19, 2015 4:03:05 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.MesosComputerLauncher launch
INFO: Sending a request to start jenkins slave mesos-jenkins-1f8691df-9918-4175-87b3-bcc3de80b258
Jun 19, 2015 4:03:05 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.JenkinsScheduler requestJenkinsSlave
INFO: Enqueuing jenkins slave request
Jun 19, 2015 4:03:05 PM hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner update
INFO: MesosCloud provisioning successfully completed. We have now 2 computer(s)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.JenkinsScheduler.matches(JenkinsScheduler.java:306)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.JenkinsScheduler.resourceOffers(JenkinsScheduler.java:252)
Jun 19, 2015 4:03:06 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.mesos.JenkinsScheduler$1 run
SEVERE: The Mesos driver was aborted! Status code: 3
```

Edit: I think I'm getting error, because I've not defined any container port mappings.
Can anyone tell me how to do so?

Update : Actually there were many problems with 0.7 version of mesos plugin. So, I simply downgraded to 0.6 version.

Answer (score 0):

For port mappings on marathon have a look [here](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually there were many problems with 0.7 version of mesos plugin. So, I simply downgraded to 0.6 version.

Comment: Hi @manish, has the downgrade helped with the issues that you faced with? I am facing with exact same issue on 0.12 and I also tried 0.8, no luck. Some of the jenkins slaves as a service are fine but with some I have the same exact issue